# GroupBy with predefined type using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've following data

```
 Id1      Id2        Days
 ------------------------
  1        1          10
  1        1          20
  1        2          30
  1        3          40
```

I want to group data by the `Id1` and `Id2` using Linq
When I do the group by as below it gives me correct result

```
List<data>.GroupBy(p => new {p.Id1, p.Id2});
```

But when I use the predefined type it gives me result as four different row groups. It doesn't combine the first 2 rows in a single group.

```
List<data>.GroupBy(p => new GroupKey(p.Id1, p.Id2));

    class GroupKey
    {
        public GroupKey(decimal _id1,decimal _id2)
        {
            Id1= _id1;
            Id2= _id2;
        }
        public decimal Id1{ get; set; }
        public decimal Id2{ get; set; }
    }
```

How to achieve the same result with predefined type?

Comment: If you're going to use that object for this you should probably make it immutable.  Mutable hash table keys are...undesirable.

Comment: i think you need to override equals if your going to use your own type for grouping .

Comment: If you're using that class _only_ for grouping then you'll find that using the anonymous type to be easier and less maintenance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the type.

Something like:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    var otherKey = other as GroupKey;

    if (otherKey == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return otherKey.Id1 == this.Id1 && otherKey.Id2 == this.Id2;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Id1.GetHashCode() ^ this.Id2.GetHashCode();
}
```

The reason this works for anonymous types (like the one you created in the first example) is because anonymous types automatically get an implementation of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` that are defined in terms of the properties defined on the anonymous type (See the "remarks" section on the "[Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)" article on MSDN).

Answer (score 1):

Use `struct` instead of `class` and make it immutable.

```
struct GroupKey
{
    public GroupKey(decimal _id1,decimal _id2):this()
    {
        Id1= _id1;
        Id2= _id2;
    }
    public decimal Id1{ get; private set; }
    public decimal Id2{ get; private set; }
}
```

First, it will take less memory than class. And second, the default struct equality behavior compares content of the structure and not reference. Which is why it is not grouping properly.

Comment: I got this error  `Error 9 Backing field for automatically implemented property GroupKey.id1' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer. `

Comment: @gmailuser Fixed. Note the added this()